# how to retrieve all spark session config variables

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks

In databricks I can set a config variable at session level, but it is not found in the context variables:

```
spark.conf.set(f"dataset.bookstore", '123') #dataset_bookstore
spark.conf.get(f"dataset.bookstore")#123
scf = spark.sparkContext.getConf()
allc = scf.getAll()
scf.contains(f"dataset.bookstore") # False
```

I understand there is a difference between session and context-level config variables, how can I retrieve all session-level variables using `spark.conf`?

Note:
all_session_vars = spark.conf.getAll()

returns

```
AttributeError: 'RuntimeConfig' object has no attribute 'getAll'
```

so it looks like a runtime-level config

Comment: Interestingly in Scala Spark `spark.conf.getAll` works fine and `spark.conf.getAll.contains("dataset.bookstore")` returns `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyspark's [`RuntimeConfig`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/RuntimeConfig.html) indeed seems to be limited compared to its [Scala counterpart](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/RuntimeConfig.html). However if we peek at its [source code](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/conf.html#RuntimeConfig)...

```
class RuntimeConfig:
    def __init__(self, jconf: JavaObject) -> None:
        """Create a new RuntimeConfig that wraps the underlying JVM object."""
        self._jconf = jconf
```

we will be able to retrieve its underlying JVM object and through that call its `getAll` method:

```
c = spark.conf._jconf.getAll()
c.contains("dataset.bookstore")  # True
```

Comment: Use `spark.conf._jconf.getAll().toString()` to list all the values. Although, you will have to read one by one since it contains default values as well.